# Finding areas of triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given that:

```
The triangles ABC and A1B1C1 are similar.
The ratio of two sides is 6:9
The sum of their areas is equal 52 (Sabc + Sa1b1c1 = 52)
```

Find the two areas

```
Sabc = ? Sa1b1c1 = ?
```

I tried to create a system, without any luck. I have no idea how to proceed any help is appriciated

Comment: If the relations between sides is $6:9=2:3$, then the relation between areas is $2^2:3^2=4:9$.

Comment: Got it the area of the first is 16 and to the second is 36. If you give this as an answer I will give it "best answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the ratio of the areas of the similar triangle $\triangle ABC$ &  $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$ is equal to the ratio of squares of their corresponding sides $$\frac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{S_{\triangle A_1B_1C_1}}=\left(\frac{6}{9}\right)^2=\frac{4}{9}$$
$$\implies S_{\triangle ABC}=\frac{4}{9}S_{\triangle A_1B_1C_1}$$
given that $$S_{\triangle ABC}+S_{\triangle A_1B_1C_1}=52$$, substituting the value
$$\frac{4}{9}S_{\triangle A_1B_1C_1}+S_{\triangle A_1B_1C_1}=52$$ 
$$\color{red}{S_{\triangle A_1B_1C_1}}=\color{blue}{36}$$
& $$\color{red}{S_{\triangle ABC}}=52-36=\color{blue}{16}$$